# C# WPF passing value between windows2 to windows1

Tags: c#, wpf, dll

First off, I'm a beginner in object oriented programming in which I'm currently finishing my final c# project.

BRIEF rundown, I have made a library class(dll) which I made it for a console application. This was my first project and then for this project I have to reuse the dll for a WPF application. I adapted my code for WPF.

I have a MainWindows for login, windows1 where the main program is working and calling the dll( collection base classes, specific name such has artist, curator and art).

My issue is that I have to use windows2 (study purpose) to sell an art. I call the dll class method which accepts 2 parameters such as (string IDArt, double SellPrice).
The mistake I did was to recreate a new instance of gallery in windows2.

I understand that I have to somehow send my(this) instance to windows2 and then retrieve the change to windows1.

I'm wondering how should I approach this issue. Please be advised that I understand c# from what I learned but i'm so far from truly knowing it and mastering it. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since C# is object-oriented, the *right* way to do this thing would be to create an instance of your `Collection` class in a lower abstract layer than a window itself (since you plan to reuse the same collection in more than one window) - for example, statically in the global `App` context - and then use data binding to synchronize the collection between your windows. (For this to work as expected, in real time, your `Collection` class needs also to implement `IObservable` and `INotifyPropertyChanged` to inform the window's context that it needs to be refreshed with new elements.)

Comment: From what I understand is that I should create a separate abstract page of my collection and send it to the required forms such has windows1 and windows2? Also I understand the Interface méthode but i didn't had much chance at practice with it same for delegate/events.

Comment: As far as I know, there already _is_ a global context, located in the file _App.xaml.cs_ (it is called such as long as you use Visual Studio).

Answer (score 1):

There are so many ways to do this, I tell you some of them..

If you want to access MainWindow fields or properties from elsewhere, you can do it like this:

In Window2:

```
//Calling MainWindow from Window2
var form = App.Current.MainWindow as ManinWindow;
form.textBox1.Text = "My Art";
MessageBox.Show(form.textBox1.Text);
```

or you can pass arguments from you Window1 to Window2 like this:

```
//Window 1
private void btnShowWindow2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var form = new Window2("My Art", 100);
    form.Show();
}

//Window 2 Constructor
public Window2(string ArtName, int Price)
{
     MessageBox.Show("ArtName: " + ArtName + "\nPrice: " Price.ToString() + " dollars");
}
```

or

```
//Window1
private void btnShowWindow2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var form = new Window2()
    {
        Price = 200,
        ArtName = "My Art"
    };
    form.Show();
}

//Window2

public string ArtName {get; set;}
public int Price {get; set;}

private void Window2_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     MessageBox.Show("ArtName: " + ArtName + "\nPrice: " Price.ToString() + " dollars");
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Ive spent ages on trying to do this and yours works (im using the first bit of code you have shown)

Answer (score 0):

probably the easiest way to do this would be to use the application's settings, also one of my favorite ways, go to "Project\WpfApp1 Properties" and go to "Settings" tab, there you can create your settings, create 1 setting name it "IDArt" and set it to a string type and another setting name it "SellPrice" and set it to double type.
now to access these settings all youhave to do is use this code:

WpfApp1.Properties.Settings.Default.IdArt;,

WpfApp1.Properties.Settings.Default.SellPrice;

Comment: Thank you everyone, with all the searching i can do and all the help I got. I finally resolved my little problem by passing my collection instance to the windows2 constructor!